# Condition inside route definition

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I just started to use `ZendFramework 2`. I defined a route in my `module.config.php` and I want to use the `$this->url` in my view to generate the url.

**`module.config.php`**

```
'settings-users-list' => array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
    'options' => array(
        'regex' => '/settings((/role/(?<role>[a-zA-Z]+))|)((/search/(?<search>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))|)((/page/(?<page>[0-9]+))|)((/date/(?<date>asc|desc))|)((/log/(?<log>asc|desc))|)',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Settings',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
        'spec' => '/settings/role/%role%/search/%search%/page/%page%/date/%date%/log/%log%',
    ),
),
```

**`In my view`**

```
echo $this->url('admin/settings-users-list',$link_params,array('force_canonical' => true));
```

where

```
$link_params = array(
    'controller' => 'settings',
    'action'     => 'index',
    'role'       => 'admin',
    'search'     => '',
    'page'       => '', 
    'date'       => '', 
    'log'        => '', 
);
```

My problem is that when a part of my parameters are empty the generated url is not the desired one. In this case the the generated url is:

```
www.mysite.com/admin/settings/role/admin/search//page//date//log/
```

Is there a way to not display `search`, `page`, `date`, `log` if this parameter is not set.  Maybe is there a way to put a condition in `spec` field of `settings-users-list` route in `module.config.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would suggest to not add the search params like `search`, `page`, `date` and `log` to your route at all. Those are query params and for this ZF2 url helper has a special `query` key in options. You can also find this in the paragraph **[Query String Arguments](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html#query-string-arguments)** in the ZF2 `url` view helper documentation. In your case you can use it like this:

```
$params = array(
    'controller' => 'settings',
    'action'     => 'index',
    'role'       => 'admin'
);

$query = array(
    'search'     => '',
    'page'       => '', 
    'date'       => '', 
    'log'        => ''
);

$options = array(
   'force_canonical' => true,
   'query' => $query
);

echo $this->url('admin/settings-users-list', $params, $options);
```

---

I would also suggest to simplify your router. It will be much more readable without a regex:

```
'settings' => array(
    'type'    => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/settings'
    )
    'may_terminate' => false,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'role' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/role/:role'
                'constraints' => array(
                    'role' => '[a-zA-Z]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Settings',
                    'action' => 'index',
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

Then you can do like this:

```
echo $this->url('settings/role', $params, $options);
```